# Javascript array structures

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array structure like below. Which I need to convert in to a different format

```
 test = [
    S1 {
        science : 90
    }
    S2
    {
        Science:80,
        Maths  :56
    }
    ]
```

I have an array which has all the subjects as below

```
 Subjects {
    Science : 0
    Maths :0
    English:0
    }
```

I want to convert my above array in to the below structure

```
S1 {
science : 90,
Maths  :0,
English:0

}
S2
{
Science:80,
Maths  :56,
English:0
}
```

which means if the subject is not available I want to enter a key value pair as 0

I tried the below

```
 for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { 
                        for (var key in test[i]) { 
                    for (var iKey in test[i][key]) { 
                varr s = (t.hasOwnProperty(iKey)) ? t[iKey] : createSubjects();
                s[key] = test[i][key][iKey];
                 t[iKey] = s;
                            }
                        }
                    }

    function createSubjects (){
                            var obj = [];
                            //categoryArray

                            for ( var a = 0, l = Subjects a < l; ++a ) {

                                 obj[Subjects [a]] = 0;
                        }

                        return obj;
                        }
```

I do not get the expected answer please some one help me to correct this. Thanks

Here is the corect code witout syntax errors

```
var test = [
    S1 = {
    science : 90

    },
S2 =
{
    Science:80,
    Maths  :56
}
]

var Subjects = {
Science : 0,
Maths :0,
English:0
}
function createSubjects (){
return {'Maths' : 0, 'Science': 0,'English':0}
}


var t = {}
console.log(createSubjects())
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { 
    for (var key in test[i]) 
    { 
            var s = (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) ? t[key] : createSubjects();
            console.log(s)
    }
}
```

What i get is 
`Object { Maths=0, Science=0, English=0}` for all the types. But What i need is

```
Object { Maths=0, Science=90, English=0} 
Object { Maths=56, Science=80, English=0}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is it that you expect, and what is it that you actually see?

Comment: You have many syntax errors, for starters. Your array definitions and for-loop statements are where two of the problems may lie.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of JavaScript arrays and objects. The output you desire is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: -1 @user1441182, This question is poorly formatted.  It is not clear exactly what you want to do.  The incorrect syntax that you have used throughout is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. Starting with your original object array (with syntax fixed):

```
var test = [
    {
        "Science": 90
    },
    {
        "Science": 80,
        "Maths": 56
    }
];
```

And then you have a desired output (a template):

```
var template = {
    "Science" : 0,
    "Maths": 0,
    "English": 0
};
```

Here's how you can convert the original array to obtain all of the properties of the template if they don't already exist (a merge of sorts):

```
function convertArray(r, t) {
   for (var i = 0, l = r.length; i < l; i++) {
       tp_loop:
        for (var tp in t) {
            for (var rp in r[i]) {
                if (!r[i].hasOwnProperty(tp)) {
                    r[i][tp] = t[tp];
                    continue tp_loop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
convertArray(test, template);
```

Here's a simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EA9KR/3/) to illustrate that it works.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question properly, this should work.

```
marks = [ s1 = { science : 90 }, s2 = { science : 80, maths : 56 } ];
for ( var i = 0; i< marks.length; i++ ) { 
 if( !(marks[i].hasOwnProperty("science"))){
   marks[i].science = 0;
 }

 if( !(marks[i].hasOwnProperty("maths"))){
   marks[i].maths = 0;
 }

 if( !(marks[i].hasOwnProperty("english"))){
   marks[i].english = 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation does not add values when the object at the array index has the property.

Comment: @tjscience thats wat he s expecting know? if it has no property with the subject name and marks it shoud add the propery with subject name and marks as 0?

Comment: He is asking to convert from one array into another, not to simply add zero values for properties that do not exist.

Comment: @tjscience oh ok.. i thought it should add the properties to the array if the property with subject and marks doesnot exist. i will change my code.